# How do i copy a group of files and change names?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a group of files

```
file_a.txt
file_b.txt
file_c.txt
...
```

I would like to make a copy of the files, but change "file" to "text". Here's how the result should look:

```
file_a.txt
file_b.txt
file_c.txt
...
text_a.txt
text_b.txt
text_c.txt
...
```

Is there a one liner in a shell that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a question for the [superuser](https://superuser.com/) forum. Anyways, it's already been answered there. See https://superuser.com/questions/353427/bash-shell-scripting-how-to-iterate-through-files-and-directories-and-copy-an. Just ignore the moving to a different folder part.